# MongoDB updating child document does not affect the original document and vise versa

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose` and have these schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(/*...*/)

const usersSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String
})


const ordersSchema = new Schema({
    user: usersSchema, // <--- ref to usersSchema
    createdOn: Date,
    // ...
})

const UsersModel = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema );
const OrdersModel = mongoose.model('Orders', ordersSchema );
```

The problem is when I insert an entity into `Users` collection and put that entity reference into the `Orders.user` field, It seems that *Mongo* does clone that object in the `Orders` collection.

```
// insert user:
var savedUser = await(new UsersModel({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    email: 'AAA@example.com'
})).save();

// insert order with user reference:
var savedOrder = await(new OrdersModel({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    createdOn: new Date(),
    user: savedUser  // <--- ref to users
})).save();
```

Now I modify the user document:

```
// update original user:
var userDocToModify = await UsersModel.findById(savedUser._id);
userDocToModify.email = "BBB@example.com";
await userDocToModify.save();
```

Assertion will fail in the below line:

```
var orderDoc = await OrdersModel.findById(savedOrder._id);
assert(orderDoc.user.email == userDocToModify.email, 'email not changed in the orderDoc.user.email!');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are doing here, is not referencing userSchema. You are embedding that schema into orders schema. If you want to reference user you should do as below:

```
const ordersSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'}
    createdOn: Date,
    // ...
})
```

In this case you just store the user id in parent document.
Now if you want to get orders and the user within it, you can either use mongoose [population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) or `$lookup` in mongoose [aggregation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html).